# Converting from Hex to Dec C/C++

Tags: hex, decimal

I have problem with conversion. My program can conversion from dec to hex but can't conversion from hex to dec. Please help me.

int main(){

```
string liczba;
while(cin>> liczba){
    int number = atoi(liczba.c_str());
if(number==-1){
    break;
}
else{
if(liczba[0]==0 && liczba[1]=='x'){
    printf("%d\n", number);
}
else{
    printf("0x%X\n", number);
}
}}

return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input string begins with "0x" then `atoi()` will always return 0, because it will stop examining the string when it sees a non-digit character (in this case the "x").  Therefore `number` will always be 0 for hexadecimal input.

The easiest solution is to use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()`.  `strtol()` called with a `base` argument of 0 will recognise the "0x" prefix and will then treat the following characters as hex digits, which is what your program needs.  That would look like this:

```
  number = strtol(liczba.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

If your platform doesn't have `strtol()` then the next-easiest solution is to use `sscanf()`, which also understands the "0x" prefix:

```
  sscanf(liczba.c_str(), "%i", &number);
```